# How to display value of a key dynamically in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am getting a JSON response like this:-

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Data found",
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "First Data"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Second Data"
    }
  ],
  "total": 3,
  "current_page": "1",
  "error": 0
}
```

In the component file, I am storing the `list` obj like this:-

```
viewPage(page,per_page){  
  this._adminPage.fetchAdminPageData(page, per_page).subscribe(
      data => {
            this.list = data.list;
            this.total_item = data.total;
            this.current_page = data.current_page;
            this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.list[0]);
          },
      err => {
            console.log(err)
          },
      () => {}
    ); 
  this.status = true;       
}
```

Using the `this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.list[0]);` I am getting the keys of `list`.

In the template page, I am writing the following code:-

```
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th *ngFor='let key of arrayOfKeys'>{{key}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

This displays **id** and **title** in the table headers. I am doing this to make the whole table dynamic.

Now, I want the values of each row would be listed by a looping through each object.

So I am trying to write something like this:-

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor='let key of arrayOfKeys'>{{key}}</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let items of list'>
        <td *ngFor='let key1 of arrayOfKeys'>[value of that key of that row]</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

`{{items.id}}` displays value of id like 1, 2. I want something like `{{items.{{key1}}` to display the value of each key, like **1** or **First Data**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]` notation for it.

```
<tr *ngFor='let items of list'>
   <td *ngFor='let key1 of arrayOfKeys'>{{ items[key1] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Kindly check that I am using another *ngFor with key1.

Comment: @Saswat Edited. Sorry

Comment: @SurenSrapyan we can use `let i = index` too right?

Comment: We can somehow use index but this is the short way